# Mounting NFS Share: Special Device Does Not Exist

Tags: raspbian, mount

I'm trying to mount a NFS share on my NAS and hitting a few troubles. I can mount the NAS myself via the `mount` command but I can't get my `/etc/fstab` right. Some help would be appreciated!

So my first attempt of:

```
sudo mount 192.168.25.100:/share/MD0_DATA/Qmultimedia /mnt/multimedia/
```

Ended up with:

```
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

OK, not too sure what's best so I've gone with...

```
sudo mount -o nolock 192.168.25.100:/share/MD0_DATA/Qmultimedia/mnt/multimedia/
```

And that maps my files as expected.  So I then I `umount` that share & try via `/etc/fstab` by adding the following line:

```
192.168.25.100:/share/MD0_DATA/Qmultimedia /mnt/multimedia auto defaults,nolock 0 0
```

Save, try `mount -a` and I'm presented with:

```
mount: special device 192.168.25.100:/share/MD0_DATA/Qmultimedia does not exist
```

Now it clearly does exist. I'm just getting some options wrong I guess. I've tried specifying the filesystem type (`ext4`) instead of auto but still no dice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `auto` mount option. You need to be specify that it is `nfs` so that it knows the first part is actually a server and not some other sort of thing.

Here's an example `fstab` line from my pi:

```
miro:/mnt/files3/videos    /home/pi/Videos3    nfs     intr,nolock    0 0
```

Comment: Great. That sounds about right & I'll give it a shot when I get home. I was referring to both [Debian's fstab page](https://wiki.debian.org/fstab) & [ArchLinux's fstab page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) for the available types. Neither mentioned `nfs`. I see it's on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) though.